# C++11 sscanf Alternative

Tags: c++11, delimiter, scanf

I need support for space, tab, and newline delimiters. I can do this with [sscanf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3.aspx) but I'd prefer to stick to strings rather than char*s.

Is there a way I can acomplish this in C++11?

Comment: What abous `streams`? Are they so bad?

Comment: How about [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)?

Comment: Streams only allow a single delimiter, unless you guys know a trick I do not.

Comment: If you use the normal input operator `>>` then *any* whitespace is a separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::istringstream is{"example input\ttext\nhere"};

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(is),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(v));

    for (const auto& s : v)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

The output from this program is

```
example
input
text
here
```

As you can see it uses any whitespace as delimiter. You can of course use the input operator as well, like in

```
std::string s;
while (is >> s)
    v.push_back(s);
```

The above instead of `std::copy` will produce the same result.